# How to generate Google Place API session token?

Tags: ios, rest, session, token, google-places-api

I'm using Google Places Autocomplete API, and I need to add a session token so I won't get charged per letter. the documentation doesn't say much.
Can I just use a random unique string as a session token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use anything as a session token. It could be "dog", "01234" etc. Google recommends [red frame](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#session_tokens) to use [UUID v4](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4) to generate this random strings.